# Struggling to get two models to have relations.  And who suffers?  The views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've got an app that sets timed challenges for users.  Each user is associated with one or more challenges.  I've setup the models so they connect via a join table.  That works fine, but I'm having problems on my view level.  In the index view for the challenges, data from the challenge model and from the user model are displayed.  But where the view should display the user's name, it's just displaying "User."  If you click on "User", you are taken to the correct "show" page for that user.  So the link works fine, but I can't get the user's name to appear.  Instead, I'm just getting the class name to appear.  Any idea why?

Here's the code for the view.  The file directly below is is views/challenges/index.html.erb

```
        <%- model_class = Challenge.new.class -%>
        <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize %></h1>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:date) %></th>
              <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:time) %></th>
              <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:rider) %></th>
              <th><%=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions") %></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= link_to challenge.date, challenge_path(challenge) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to challenge.duration, challenge_path(challenge) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to challenge.users.name, user_path(challenge) %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here's the relevant models.
Challenge.rb

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :duration, :user

  has_many :user_challenges
  has_many :users, :through  => :user_challenges
  validates_presence_of :date, :duration

  def self.winner
    Challenge.find(:first, :order => "duration desc")
  end

end
```

User.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :email

    has_many :user_challenges
    has_many :challenges, :through => :user_challenges

    validates_presence_of :name, :email
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

    def self.find_or_create(name, email)
      user = User.find_by_email(email)
      if user.present?
        user.challenge = challenge
        user.save
      else
        User.create(:name => name, :email => email)
      end
    end
  end
```

Join table, aka User_challenge.rb

```
class UserChallenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`challenge.users` is a collection and `.name` is a ruby method that gives you the name of the class:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :002 > Object.name
 => "Object"
```

Call the attribute something else (username).

Also, `user_path(challenge)` doesn't really make sense when a `Challenge` can `have_many :users` (which users path should it be?).

Comment: I renamed the "name" column in the User table to "username", but now the line that refers to username (` <td><%= link_to challenge.users.username, user_path(challenge) %></td>`) is causing an undefined method error.  I modified the User.rb file to refer to "username" instead of "name," but it didn't solve the problem. Is there something else I need to modify?

Comment: `challenge.users.first.username`. `challenge.users` is a collection of all the challenge's users (has_many).

Comment: I understand that I need to shift from calling the collection, to calling an individual username, but `challenge.users.first.username` still throws up a no method erros.  It considers "first" a nil class and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I think the users list is empty, and that's why users.first.username is nil.
the user_path(challenge) 'seems' like its working, but its probably always taking you to the users/challenge_id path, which is not what you want.

most likely something isn't saving correctly for you. verify that your users lists are not empty. hop in the console and test out the saving and reloading of your data

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  Once I fixed that, the `challenges.users.first.username` code worked fine.  Your intuition was correct!  Thanks for helping me work through this.